# Validate a Wikipedia page name

Tags: code-golf

Wikipedia has [several restrictions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Naming_conventions_%28technical_restrictions%29) on an article's title. I summarize them here:

- It may not be empty.
- It may not begin with a lowercase letter. A character is considered lowercase if it has an `Ll` after its name in [UnicodeData.txt](ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/UnicodeData.txt).
- It may not contain any of the characters: `# < > [ ] | { } _`
- It may not be `.` or `..`
- It may not begin with `./` or `../`.
- It may not contain `/./` or `/../`.
- It may not end with `/.` or `/..`.
- It may not contain any space character (a character is considered a space if it has `Zs` after its name in UnicodeData.txt) except for `U+0020 SPACE`.
- It may not contain more than one consecutive space.
- It may not consist entirely of spaces.
- It may not begin with a colon.
- It may not begin with the language prefix of any of the [292 language editions of Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Wikipedias) followed by a colon. This includes `en:` for English.
- It may not begin with the prefix of [another Wikimedia Foundation project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Interwiki_linking) or its shortcut followed by a colon.
- It may not contain the character `%` followed by two hexadecimal digits.
- It may not contain a named [HTML character entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references). Numbered entities are already forbidden through `#`.
- It must contain no more than 256 bytes when encoded in UTF-8.

Write a function that takes in a string (or whatever data type your language normally uses to manipulate text) and outputs a boolean indicating whether the string is a valid Wikipedia article title. You are permitted to use networking libraries to download and read from any page that I linked in this question.

Comment: `true/false` or `yes/no`? The latter will save me some bytes :p

Comment: This question needs a lot of work: it contains multiple links to required external data which is likely to change, and has several unclear requirements.

Comment: For the second condition, is the Greek small letter eta (η) allowed?

Comment: @feersum Please explain all of what is unclear, so I can fix it. The external data will be referenced by the revision of those pages at the moment I made this question

Comment: I am not going to list all that is unclear as there is too much. Here's a few questions to start with: 1. Does `may not contain more than one consecutive space or underscore` apply to underscore followed by space, or space followed by undescore? 2. What counts as an HTML entity? Only a finite list of them, any characters between `&` and `#`, or ... ? 3. No reference is given for which Unicode characters count as spaces or lowercase letters.

Comment: @feersum All those problems have been fixed.

Comment: This is extremely far from self-contained. Please avoid external links in challenges.

Answer (score 4):

## Retina, 1221 bytes

```
^(?=...:|\w|(^|.*/)\.\.?(/.*|$)|.*([#<>\[\]|{}]|  |__|%[0-9a-fA-F]{2}|&#(\d{4}|[0-9a-fA-F]{4}|a(mp|pos)|(l|g|quo)t);|~~~)|[ _]*$|.{257,}).*
no
^(?!no$).+
yes
```

where `...` is:

```
(w(ik(i(s(pecies|ource)|v(ersity|oyage)|([mp]edi|dat)a|(book|new)s|quote|tech)|t(ionary)?)|m(i[dlnt]|c[ahz]|a[ru]|b[de]|d[ek]|h[ku]|n[lo]|r[su]|u[ak]|fi?|mk|pl|se|tw)|ar?|uu|o)?|m(e(dia(wikiwiki|zilla)|t(awikipedi)?a)|a(p-bms|i)|[klnr]|[ghi]|[iz]n|[st]|yv?|df|hr|rj|us|wl)|s([degh]|t(rategy|q)|i(mple)?|[klmnoqr]|c(n?|o)|pecies|[uvw]|[st]|ah?|rn|zl)|b(a(t-smg|r?)|ug(zilla)?|e-tarask|[eghi]|[mno]|[rs]|cl|jn|py|xr)|t([aghw]|e(stwiki|t)?|[iklno]|oollabs|[rst]|yv?|pi|um)|c(o(mmons)?|h[ory]?|[es]b?|bk-zam|[uvy]|rh?|do|kb|a)|p(habricator|a[gmp]?|n[bt]|[st]|f?l|ih?|cd|dc|ms)|n(ds(-nl)?|[glno]|a[hp]?|[vy]|ew?|ov|rm|so)|a([afkm]|r[cz]?|[vyz]|ng?|st?|z?b|ce|dy|ls)|k([gijklmnor]|[uvwy]|a[ab]?|sh?|bd|oi|rc)|z(h(-(classical|min-nan|yue))?|e?a|u)|f([afijory]|oundation|iu-vro|r[pr]|ur)|l([gi]|[no]|ad?|be?|tg?|ez|ij|mo|rc|v)|r([nw]|o(a-(tara|rup))?|my?|ue?)|g(a[gn]?|[dln]|o[mt]|[uv]|lk)|h([eiortu]|a[kw]?|[yz]|if|sb)|i([adegikostu]|ncubator|lo)|v(e(c?|p)|oy?|ls|i)|d([vz]|[ae]|iq|sb)|e([elnostu]|ml|xt)|u([gz]|[kr]|dm)|j([av]|bo)|x(al|mf|h)|[nbqsvcdm]|o[cmrs]|y[io]|qu|)
```

(I used [this regex optimizer](https://myregextester.com/index.php) and manutally typed in all the data)

[Try it online without the `...`!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=Xig_PVthLXo6XXwoXnwuKi8pXC5cLj8oLy4qfCQpfC4qKFsjPD5cW1xdfHt9XXwgIHxfX3wlWzAtOWEtZkEtRl17Mn18JiMoXGR7NH18WzAtOWEtZkEtRl17NH18YShtcHxwb3MpfChsfGd8cXVvKXQpO3x-fn4pfFsgX10qJHwuezI1Nyx9KS4qCm5vCl4oPyFubyQpLisKeWVz&input=QWJjJiMyNTYzOw)

Comment: Does this test for all the lowercase letters? There are a lot more than 26 of them, there are 1984 of them according to that file.